# How do I change Bootstrap 3 div column order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

doing my 1st responsive design and is something like this possible in bootstrap 3. Change this on lg:

```
[a] [     ]
[b] [  c  ]
    [     ]
```

to this on sm:

```
[a]
[c]
[b]
```

Comment: You can use hidden-sm class - check the reference here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: You want [ c ] to stack down on sm. So isn't the order in sm should be [a][b][c]? Since c is on same level as b, so if it stacks down on small screen , it will go below b.

Comment: c is not at the same level as b, it is on the same level as div for A and B

Answer (score 0):

You can use two div. One is for first type of arrangements and other is for second type of arrangements. The first is only shown in lg and and last one is only in sm.

```
<div class="hidden-sm">

</div>

<div class="hidden-lg">

</div>
```

Comment: i was finking about this. Is hiding elements is the right way too do this? Can their be any other methods?

Comment: for responsiveness you can add class as per your need like col-lg-8 like.

Comment: Hiding div not having problem. This is the solutions that i know.

Comment: bootstrap support ie 9 and 9+ only. So it will supoort only ie 9 and 9+

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML markup, place the [c] between [a] and [b]. Add class 'pull-left' to a and b. Add class 'pull- right' to c. Finally, contain them in a div that defines breakpoints e.g class='col-sm-12 col-md-12'.

Comment: I have another question for you, what if i want to get [b][c][a] on sm, is it possible to do this using html an bootstarp methods?

Comment: Mark question as answered for others who may come along. About the second question,  i'm not getting it quite well.....the col-sm-12 class handles that. Unless you want smaller div? Use a smaller number in place of  12.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pull-right` on column C... A-C-B on mobile.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="a col-lg-6">
        A
     </div>
     <div class="c col-lg-6 pull-right">
        B
     </div>
     <div class="b col-lg-6">
        C
     </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**: http://bootply.com/9UNb9Q37G0