# Bootstrap: move div from one column to another, order counts for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div>block1 with IDs and classes</div>
        <div>block2 with IDs and classes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div>block3 with IDs and classes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make it look like

```
block1 
block3 
block2
```

for mobile?

P.S. Of course I took a look at this questions before I asked mine:

[SO: How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

**It doesn't help.**
Also, adding `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` for two blocks of

```
<div>block2 with IDs and classes</div>
```

in different places doesn't help as IDs should be unique on the page.

Any suggestions? Thank you.
Example:
[image]

**IMPORTANT: block 3 may be (and it is) taller (the height is bigger) than block1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use push/pull. Just think "mobile-first"..

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div>block1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div>block3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div>block2</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/jgvSJrMOnk

In the case where `block 3` is taller than the other columns, create a special class to float it to the right on large screens..

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .pull-lg-right {
      float:right;
    }
}
```

Related:
[How do I change Bootstrap 3 div column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961980/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-div-column-order/27963548#27963548)
[Bootstrap with different order on mobile version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882342/bootstrap-with-different-order-on-mobile-version/4888575) (Bootstrap 4)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted.. not me... . I liked your answer BUT...SADLY, the block2 for large devices comes much lower than block 3: https://jsfiddle.net/wr22s3qc/   Do you see it looks sadly wrong?

Comment: yeah, hieght makes a difference. Add a special class to float:right on large screens. [Updated example](http://www.codeply.com/go/jgvSJrMOnk)

Comment: please also update your answer. This is the correct answer: jsfiddle.net/wr22s3qc

Comment: Cool, I will. Please also update the question to indicate that block 3 is taller. The right float is only needed when the column in taller.

Comment: the question was updated (added information about the height) - the very last sentence in bold, under the image. I'm curious who downvoted your answer. Your answer is correct!

Comment: @ZimSystem is this possible in BS4?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - you probably are looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882342/bootstrap-with-different-order-on-mobile-version/4888575).

Comment: @ZimSystem yeah, floats(( we have here battle on what to use CSS Grids or BS4. I used grids not much but it seems to me we will have to implement BS columns system with CSS Grid which will take a lot of time. so I'm trying to show BS4 is not so bad but everyone wants grids...

Answer (score 1):

using push and pull properties of grid will do your work try this the push and pull will be only applied for small device

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">block1 with IDs and classes</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-push-12">block2 with IDs and classes</div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-pull-12">block3 with IDs and classes</div>
    </div>
```

**Edit** clearfix added for large device

Comment: Sorry, for large screen your code https://jsfiddle.net/5dkmx4vx/  is not correct as it shows all blocks in one line, but block2 supposed to be UNDER block1 for large devices.

Comment: Sorry, it is still different. I will attach the image in a minute or two.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The `col-sm-*-12` pushes the cols off the screen.