# Bootstrap with different order on mobile version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 column and nested row in right column, how can i make  bootstrap  responsive like below,

layout :

```
desktop version
--------- ------
|   2   ||  1  |
|       ||     |
|       |-------
|       ||  3  |
|       ||     |
|       |-------
|       |
|       |
---------

mobile version (stacked in order)
--------
|  1   |
|      |
--------
|  2   |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
--------
|  3   |
|      |
--------
```

this is my code :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">1
     </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">3
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-8 order-lg-first">2
   </div>
</div>
```

With this code the order in mobile version 1 3 2, what I want is 1 2 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox, the **columns are always going to be equal height**, and you'll not be able to get the desktop (lg) layout that you want.

**One option** is to disable the flexbox for `lg`. Use **floats** so that the 1,3 columns naturally pull to the right, since 2 is taller. The flexbox `order-` will work on mobile.

https://codeply.com/go/8lsFAU3C5E

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex d-lg-block">
         <div class="col-lg-8 order-1 float-left">
            <div class="card card-body tall">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 order-0 float-left">
            <div class="card card-body">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 order-1 float-left">
            <div class="card card-body">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How this works**

- Keep columns in the same row, since ordering is relative to parent
- The `d-flex d-lg-block` disables flex on `lg` and up
- The `float-left` float the columns when flex is disabled
- The `order-*` reorder the columns when flex is enabled

**Another option** is some flexbox wrapping hack that uses `w-auto`...

https://codeply.com/go/mKykCsBFDX

---

Also see:
[How to fix unexpected column order in bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306652/how-to-fix-unexpected-column-order-in-bootstrap-4)
[Bootstrap Responsive Columns Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169932/bootstrap-responsive-columns-height/52170107#52170107)

B-A-C -> A-B-C

Comment: This doesn't work if column 1 is higher than column 2. IN that case 3 will sit under 2, to the left of 1. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Just to answer my own question, add `float-right` rather than left to 3 to keep it on the right if 2 is shorter than 1.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve that in Bootstrap 4, you need the `order-lg-first` class for the "2" column and the `offset-lg-8` class for the "3" column (assuming they are ordered 1-2-3 in the HTML).

The `offset-lg-8` class will offset (i.e. push to the right) the third column by 8 units (=the same as the width of the second column) on screens that are large (`lg`) or larger thus producing the desired result.

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 bg-warning">1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 order-lg-first bg-secondary">2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-8 bg-warning">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but there is white space between "1" and "3" in desktop version if  height of "2" more than "1". is there work around this ? (the "3" always under "1" in desktop version ).  thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the height of "2" on desktop must be independent of the other divs?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I did the same solution that you explained, but like the OP said, now there is a height (space) between 1 and 3 (only on lg and above, works perfect in smaller screen sizes). Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use push and pull to change the order of the columns. See more info [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap)

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```