# Rearranging responsive Bootstrap 4 grid layout

Tags: bootstrap-4

Let's say you have a page with four main blocks in it (they would each contain varying amounts of content):

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

At narrow browser widths they should appear in the same order they are in the HTML:

[image]

But at wider widths they should rearrange into this layout, with a sidebar, with the blocks in a different order:

[image]

*Using Bootstrap 4's grid layout* is there a way to do this? I can see how to [reorder](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes) blocks, but that only seems to be good for blocks within the same row.

**UPDATE:** The second layout could be done like this, but I can't see a way to make that look like the first layout:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div>3</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this particular scenario can't be done just with Flexbox like you need to; I see a better fit for CSS Grid; as you say; for order clases to work like that all elements need to be on the same row; and that layout won't allow it.... The other option is to hide one column on certain sizes

Comment: @Zim If I had any code that was useful then I would... but then I would have answered my own question :)

Comment: Thanks @IvanS95 I thought that might be the case, but wondered if I'd missed something. Flexbox is only really suited to a sequence of blocks (horizontally or vertically), rather than completely rearranging things...

Comment: @Zim I've added example code for the second layout, but I'm not sure that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882342/bootstrap-with-different-order-on-mobile-version). There is a way with Bootstrap 4, but you need to use **floats** instead of flexbox.

Here `d-sm-block` is used to apply the floats only on `sm` and wider. Flexbox is used for mobile which allows the ordering to work.

```
<div class="row d-sm-block">
    <div class="col-sm-9 order-2 order-md-0 float-left">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-3 order-md-0 float-right">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-1 order-md-0 float-right">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-4 order-md-0 float-right">4</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ksaw8Aq2lP

Comment: Can it be made so the `height` is the same for the two "columns"?

Comment: That is cunning Zim, thank you! I'll have a play with that. fwiw I'm not expecting the columns to be the same height, but @IvanS95 is obviously more demanding :)

Comment: Yeah; in codeply the element 2 looks a bit taller than the rest; can the other 3 elements be aligned to that as well? (I'm just curious lol)

Comment: Yeah that's not what OP showed in the wider layout image. I assumed 2 was taller like the image.