# Is this kind of layout possible with only flexbox or bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Attached you can see an image of what I'm trying to do. Is it possible using just flexbox and bootstrap4?

[image: layout]

Edit: what I've tried: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRwaJL

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="left-div">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="right-div">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="left-div">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="left-div">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="right-div">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
.left-div {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.right-div {
  background-color: darkgray;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: yes, please post the markup you've tried so far

Comment: It is possible using either `flexbox` or `grid` and bootstrap-4. Add the code you've tried so far

Comment: Edited to include code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox, so columns in each row are the same height. The desktop layout could be achieved using nesting with 2 outer columns. However, to change the order/position of the columns, as you want for mobile, the columns must all be in the same `.row`...

Therefore, you can "disable" the flexbox on `md` and larger using the `d-block` 
class along with the float utility classes. On smaller mobile widths, the flexbox behavior will kick back in, and the `order-*` classes can be used to position the columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-md-block">
        <div class="col-md-8 order-1 float-left">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-3 float-right">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 order-2 float-left">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 order-5 float-right">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 order-4 float-left">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/5z7096wfGO

---

Related: [Rearranging responsive Bootstrap 4 grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264243/rearranging-responsive-bootstrap-4-grid-layout/55264594#55264594)

Comment: Thanks! That's a step forward, but I need other rows after it as well...
Adding another 'row' doesn't work because the first row doesn't take all the height of it's children.

Comment: The question didn't mention more rows or columns. It just shows the 5 for which you now have an answer ;-) .. this is the way using only Bootstrap 4

Comment: Adding .clearfix to the first row solves it. Thanks!

Comment: A declaration of `.container {display: grid;}` would work well here.