# Reordering bootstrap columns(nested)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

So I have three columns in bootstrap and are the following

Mobile:

```
[A]
[C]
[B]
```

Desktop:

```
[A][C]
[B]
```

Following is my code:

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
     <div class="content1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        A
       <div class="row">
          <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
             B
          </div>   
       </div>
     </div>     
  <div class="content3 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        C
  </div>
  <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
       B
  </div>          
</div>
```

I have achieved it using hidden classes, but is there a better way to do it using push/pull classes for example?

PS: I have a fixed height for [C], lets say 50vh.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap v4.1 then it is possible with the flex order.

Comment: @ZimSystem v3 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use nesting, push/pull or hidden classes. Use 50% width columns on larger `md` widths.

https://www.codeply.com/go/3APQ7tHCgS

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content1 col-md-6">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="content3 col-md-6">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="content2 col-md-12">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, note that `col-xs-12` is implied in Bootstrap 3 when a larger grid column is used so it's not needed in the markup.

Related: [How do I change Bootstrap 3 div column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961980/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-div-column-order/27963548#27963548)

Comment: hey thanks for that... i have already tried that and it won't help in my case since content 3 has some fixed height!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ouub4kw/24/)...

```css
.content1{height:50vh !important;}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <div class="content1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    A
  </div>     
  <div class="content3 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="content2 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    B
  </div>          
</div>
```

I think its working in both sizes (mobile and desktop).